# With Spanish babel, reference number of theorems appear with commas

Tags: cross-referencing, spanish

I guess it happens because in Spanish decimal numbers are with commas. Is there any nice workaround for this? Thanks

I include a minimal working example (notice that the bug happens only when you have  the reference with underset).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,final]{book}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcounter{dummy} \numberwithin{dummy}{section}

\newtheorem{thm}[dummy]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[dummy]{Lemma}

% También podría poner ordinales.

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

%TODO no sé si es subsection
\section{Basics}

\begin{lem}
\label{fundamental}
    Water is wet.
\end{lem}

\begin{proof}
   It's obvious.
\end{proof}


\begin{thm}
    Snow will be wet when it melts.
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}

We'll use Lemma \ref{fundamental}.

    Snow is frozen water$\underset{Lemma\ \ref{fundamental}}{\Rightarrow}$ it will be wet when it melts.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image: Minimal working example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Lemma ...." is a text and should not be set in math mode - as a side effect, the commas are replaced by periods.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,final]{book}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcounter{dummy} \numberwithin{dummy}{section}

\newtheorem{thm}[dummy]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[dummy]{Lemma}

% También podría poner ordinales.

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

%TODO no sé si es subsection
\section{Basics}

\begin{lem}
\label{fundamental}
    Water is wet.
\end{lem}

\begin{proof}
   It's obvious.
\end{proof}


\begin{thm}
    Snow will be wet when it melts.
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}

We'll use Lemma \ref{fundamental}.

    Snow is frozen water$\underset{\text{Lemma\ \ref{fundamental}}}{\Rightarrow}$ it will be wet when it melts.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Off-topic: but please don't load the same package multiple times)

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, sorry, in my original document that doesn't happen :P. I'll edit it in the question

Answer (score 0):

An obvious workaround is to include:

```
\decimalpoint
```

and in fact I can do it because my thesis doesn't include decimal numbers, but I'm courious if another more elegant solution is available (that fixes the problem without changing this)